# Google Chrome renames file .xml to .download

Tags: php, html, xml, google-chrome

i have this very simple download page to get an xml file.
the script works ok in firefox/IE. but chrome renames the extension of the file to ".download".
and this happens only to .xml, when you use another extension like .txt it does it without problems.

the body of the html is this:

```
<body>
  <a href="down.php">descarga</a>
</body>
```

and the php is this:

```
header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="example.xml"');
echo "that's it";
```

its very strange. any solution for this??

Comment: you need to stop submitting updates every 30 seconds attempting to format your code when it has been completely done for you three times already. There's a preview section for a reason, try using it instead of submitting edits simply to check your formatting.

Comment: thanks. i didnt know how to format the code. sorry for the mistake. got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a definite answer, just some information for you.

From the [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29913):

> The downloaded file may get a different name if it is considered potentially dangerous 
>   for your computer (e.g. exe). You should then get an UI prompt in the download shelf 
>   asking you to confirm the download (with the file still downloading in the background).

Comment: right. the file is downloaded, the only problem is the extension rename. i wasn´t expecting a xml file to be considered potentially dangerous.

Comment: Well, for now the only option i have is to place a warning for the user saying to check the extension in case he/she is using Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

try removing 'echo "that's it";'
it makes the xml invalid and might confuse the browser.
if it doesn't help, check the actual http headers of both request and response.